# Angular2 pipes filter links in HTML string

Tags: angular

Since I get my HTML string from an external source, I want to filter all the links that contains images, remove the href attribute and replace it with (click) event... I'm trying to do this with a angular pipe, the pipe is only removing the href attribute but the click event is not working

I tried `a.onclick = this.showLightbox;`, 
and I tried `a.addEventListener("click", this.showLightbox, false);`

but both didn't work

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'lightboxPipe'})
export class LightboxPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {

    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = value;

    [].forEach.call(div.getElementsByTagName("img"), (img) => {
      var a = img.parentElement;
      a.removeAttribute('href');
      a.onclick = this.showLightbox;
    });

    return div.innerHTML;
  }

  showLightbox(){
    console.log('a link has been clicked');
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try: `a.onclick = () => this.showLightbox;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'lightboxPipe'})
export class LightboxPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, el): string {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = value;

    [].forEach.call(div.getElementsByTagName("img"), (img) => {
      var a = img.parentElement;
      a.removeAttribute('href');
      a.onclick = () => this.showLightbox(img.src);
    });

    el.appendChild(div);
  }

  showLightbox(src){
    console.log('a link has been clicked');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div #el>{{ html | lightboxPipe: el }}</div>`,
  pipes: [LightboxPipe]
})
export class App { 
  html = '<a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>';
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q6Bb3Ge3maTXLy6mfONb?p=preview)**